# Issue with sorting with collection in java

Tags: java

I have a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String,QuoteBean> map = new HashMap<String,QuoteBean>();
```

The `QuoteBean` is a normal bean:

```
class QuoteBean{
    String symbol;
    BigDecimal price;
    BigDecimal quoteprice;
    //setter and getter methods
}
```

Then, I get the values of the map which a collection of `QuoteBean` objects

```
Collection obs  =map.values(); //getting all the quoteobjects
List list = new ArrayList(obs); //converted to list
```

Then to sort:

```
Collection.sort(list, new SymbolComparator());
```

`SymolComparator` is:

```
public class SymbolComparator implements Comparator<QuoteBean>{
    String symbol;
    @Override
    public int compare(QuoteBean o1, QuoteBean o2) {
        String symbol1=o1.getProductId().getSymbol();
        String symbol2=o2.getProductId().getSymbol();
        return symbol1.compareTo(symbol2);
    }    
}
```

When I execute the code I get an exeception which says cannot convert `String` to `QuoteBean` and the exception throws on the first line.

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace?

Comment: Something tells me this isn't actually the code that's causing the error.

Comment: In the compare() method, you do o1.getProductId()... what does getProductId() return?

Answer (score 2):

Are you positive you're not creating a list from the keys?

```
Collection obs  =map.values(); //getting all the quoteobjects
List list = new ArrayList(obs);
```

Just for fun make sure you can do

```
List<QuoteBean> beans = new ArrayList<QuoteBean>(map.values());
```

Comment: I am pretty sure i am getting the values only from the map because once i get the list i am iterating through the list and printing the content which prints all the values...

Comment: Give us the stack trace, and start putting some debugging statements in your comparator function and we'll be able to help a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

I think the mistake is with these two statements...

```
String symbol1=o1.getProductId().getSymbol();
String symbol2=o2.getProductId().getSymbol();
```

if you want to sort the based on string you could just say o1.symbol to get the string. I still don;t understand what getproductid() is used for.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
o1.getProductId().getSymbol();
```

you should do

```
o1.getSymbol();
```

since the QuoteBean has the symbol as a property.

```
class QuoteBean{
    String symbol;
    BigDecimal price;
    BigDecimal quoteprice;
    //setter and getter methods
}
```